# Create key via SQL and C# for partition key

Tags: c#, sql, hashcode, service-fabric-stateful, azure-service-fabric

I have a set of data which has a hierarchy of 3 levels. Each level has a name.

I am looking at combining all of these names into a single string then creating a numeric hash that can be used as a hash key for a  service fabric stateful service.

I have seen lots online about finding data with keys but I am not sure how to actually create them in an efficient way.

Ideally I would like a hash that is quick and easy to generate in SQL Server 2017 and C#.

Can anyone point me in the right direction, please?

Paul

Comment: Usually you combine the string with a characters that is not in the strings.  So a lot of people use the "^".  So if you have strings a, b, c use string.Join("^", new string[] { a, b, c});

Comment: Ok not sure how this would get a numeric hash?

Comment: @jdweng That's a very inefficient way of doing that...

Comment: To clarify, you mean you have a large set of C# POCO classes that you want to both serialize and hash? To be "correct" you'll want to hash the output of your serialization function. How are you serializing your objects?

Comment: I understand the best hash-algorithm for speed and uniqueness (you do **not** want to use a cryptographic hash function because those are deliberately not optimized for speed) is something like MurmurHash: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MurmurHash

Comment: @Dai: The hash need to be unique 100% of the time.  Many of the posting I've seen do not give a unique hash under every condition.  If a cryptographic algorithm is used it cannot be a password algorithm that is not reversible that will give a one-to-many mapping.  It must be a one-to-one that is reversible.

Comment: Use string.Join("^", new string[] { a, b, c}).GetHashCode();  I'm not sure what is efficient about this method.

Comment: @jdweng It is impossible to have 100% unique hashes - and a “reversible hash” is an oxymoron.

Comment: Then how do you guarantee the code will ALWAYS work without unique hashes?  Without unique hashes when a comparison is performed between two objects you can incorrectly get wrong results.

Comment: This is not about unique hashes as such I need consistent hashes.  If I give the text "LEVEL 1 LEVEL 2 LEVEL 3" I want the same hash code to be generated each time.  I am not serializing anything, I just want to give a method a string and that method to give me back a numeric hash value I can use as a partition key in Service Facric

Comment: @Paul as far as I understand you want to use numeric value as key based on the hierarchy path of the item in database. If I am right you don't need hash function you need to create associations between hierarchy path and numeric value because hash function cannot guarantee uniqueness. I am not sure where this association can be implemented because I can't see a design, so if you can provide a bit more information maybe I would be able to help.

Comment: I don’t really need uniqueness I need something that will generate keys that’s are spread nicely across my nodes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The SF team [advice](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-concepts-partitioning) is to use the FNV-1 hashing algorithm for this.

> Select a hash algorithm An important part of hashing is selecting your
>   hash algorithm. A consideration is whether the goal is to group
>   similar keys near each other (locality sensitive hashing)--or if
>   activity should be distributed broadly across all partitions
>   (distribution hashing), which is more common.
>
> The characteristics of a good distribution hashing algorithm are that
>   it is easy to compute, it has few collisions, and it distributes the
>   keys evenly. A good example of an efficient hash algorithm is the
>   FNV-1 hash algorithm.
>
> A good resource for general hash code algorithm choices is the
>   Wikipedia page on hash functions.

A C# implementation in this example [here](https://github.com/loekd/ServiceFabric.Dictionary/blob/master/ServiceFabric.Dictionary.IndexService/HashingHelper.cs#L8):

```
public long HashString(string input)
{
    input = input.ToUpperInvariant();
    var value = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(input);
    ulong hash = 14695981039346656037;
    unchecked
    {
       for (int i = 0; i < value.Length; ++i)
       {
          hash ^= value[i];
          hash *= 1099511628211;
       }        
       return (long)hash;
    }
}
```

Remove the `ToUpperInvariant` to make it case sensitive.